# Complex aggregate functions and hierarchical structures in SQL

Tags: sql, aggregate, nested-sets

I want to store a tree structure of arbitrary depth in an SQL database (MySQL, but want to avoid DBMS-specific features). Now I want to compute a value *N* for each node as follows:

- first, calculate the sum of a certain column in all (immediate) children of the current node which are leaves (i.e. have no children)
- then, calculate the maximum of the values *N* of each of the remaining children, i.e. those with children
- finally, add the results of the first two steps to get the value *N* for the current node

Obviously, this involves a recursion, so nested sets seem to be the representation of choice for this scenario. However, I couldn't work out how to formulate the calculation above as an SQL query. It is easy to get the SUM() or MAX() of all the descendants, but the way the aggregate functions are combined complicates the matter greatly. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: That is a painful calculation.  Can you afford to store the value N in the nodes?  Also, is each node constrained to appear once in the hierarchy as a whole, or can a node appear in several places?  (Consider the difference between an org chart and a bill-of-materials for building some assembly.)

Comment: Would you be willing to change to a different database that does support recursive queries? If you are not willing to consider using a different database, then why do you have the requirement to avoid using MySQL specific features?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Each node can only appear once, and the non-leave nodes contain en empty column anyway (where the leave nodes store their value). However, AFAICS this would require to pre-calculate the values during insert/update, which would render the whole exercise void...

Comment: @Mark Byers: This question arose mainly out of academic interest; in practice, all my trees tend to be shallow and to contain only a handful of nodes, so I will probably just fetch them all and do the calculation client-side.

Answer (score 1):

What if the schema also had additional computed columns such as depth and "is leaf node"?

It would require more maintenance (not that nested sets are maintenance free) but I think it puts the above query within reach using "standard" SQL.

Comment: This would be ok, but probably unnecessary, as both depth and "is leaf node" can be calculated during the query.